# I2C: What is the difference between A4&A5 and SCL&SDA pins?

Tags: i2c

On tutorials are most people using the A4&A5 pins with the Wire.h library. But i have an arduino with dedicated I²C pins. How can i use them? 
[image: Arduino]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are the same pins. They are physically connected to each other on the UNO board. (So SDA is connected to A4. SCL is connected to A5)